# AngularJS filter fuzzy search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a filter in my controller like this:

```
$scope.LegEntQueue = $filter('filter')(legEncoderQueue, {FileAppCD: 'ENT'}).length;
```

Where I am counting the results of an array called `legEncoderQueue` based on a property called `FileAppCD` if it has the value of `ENT`

This works perfectly, but is there a way to have it fuzzy search and select anything that has `ENT` in the value?  Such as `ENT-M-And` and `ENT-M-iOS`?

Comment: you could to `.filter` over collection with your own code condition(regex) plain javascript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input, it took me a moment to realize my ignorance, thinking I could just use some built in angular filter to do what just plain javascript could do.

My Solution, was to create a function:

```
$scope.regexCount = function(array, feild, pattern) {
    var count = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (pattern.test(array[index][feild])) {
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return count;
};
```

And then pass in my parameters.

`$scope.LegEntQueue = $scope.regexCount(legEncoderQueue, 'FileAppCD', /ENT.*/);`

Answer (score 2):

There's a property `$` that will perform a substring search of all your properties within your collection. In your case, you can use

```
$scope.LegEntQueue = $filter('filter')(legEncoderQueue, {$: 'ENT'})
```

[From the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

> A special property name ($ by default) can be used (e.g. as in {$:
>   "text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its
>   nested object properties.

Comment: Sorry I didn't word that right, I want to select all objects with `{FileAppCD: 'ENT'}` or `{FileAppCD: 'ENT-M-And'}` or `{FileAppCD: 'ENT-M-iOS'}`  and so on.  I have like 15 different FileAppCD values that start with ENT and I'd like to select them all in one go, instead of writing 15 separate filter statements.

Comment: @Greyhammer I'd suggest specifying a filter function and use a regular expression or any custom logic if you need more control.